# AutoMapper Ignore the Mapping Conditionally when the List type of property in ViewModel is null

Tags: c#, automapper, automapper-6

I have the view model as below:

```
public class CarViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string CarName { get; set; }
    public List<EngineTypeViewModel> Engine { get; set; }
}

public class EngineTypeViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Entity:

```
public class Car
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string CarName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<EngineType> Engine { get; set; }
}
public class EngineType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

I wanted to Map the CarViewModel to Car Entity types as below:

```
CreateMap<CarViewModel, Car>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Engine, src => src.Ignore());
```

In the mapping configuration I wanted to map from `CarViewModel` to `Car`.
But if the engine `count is 0` then the mapped should be ignore.

```
CreateMap<CarViewModel, Car>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Engine, src => src.Ignore()); 
//Map only when src.Engine.Count > 0 other wise Ignore
// What should be my approach here??
```

This means during the update when i pull using `GetById`. Like

```
public Update(CarViewModel model)
{
   var car = obj.GetById(model.Id);
   var mapped = map.Map(model,car); 

   //if the model.Engine.Count = 0 car.Engine 
   //should be same as mapped.Engine, there should not be mapping with the 
   //object(Engine) from the `CarViewModel`
}
```

Is there any extension in Auto mapper to this task. I have tried as above `src.Ignore()` it is going to ignore during the `ADD` also.

So, I do not want to MAP the null value during the Update. Or, it should remain as the destination value

Edit:

AutoMapper Configuration:

```
CreateMap<CarViewModel, Car>().ForMember(dest => dest.Engine, o =>
{
    o.Condition(src => src.Engine.Count > 0);

    //mapping
    o.MapFrom(src => src.Engine);
});
```

Mapping Records:

```
var carmodel = new CarViewModel();
carmodel.CarName = "Maruti";
carmodel.Id = Guid.NewGuid();

var carentity = new Car();
carentity.CarName = "Maruti";
carentity.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
carentity.Engine.Add(new EngineType { Id = 1, name = "PetrolEngine" });
carentity.Engine.Add(new EngineType { Id = 2, name = "DieselEngine" });
carentity.Engine.Add(new EngineType { Id = 3, name = "CranotEngine" });


var mapped = _mapper.Map(carmodel, carentity);
```

You can look at the `mapped`. `mapped.Engine is Empty`

[image]

Expected Output:

[image]

Comment: So is it ok to use 0 when the item is new? If so just use a ternary `src => src.Engine.Count != 0 ? src.Engine.Count : 0;`

Comment: If the item is new the Engine Count is not allowed to be 0. This is prevented from UI.